# Rotating a car model squeezes it all together

Tags: animation, cycles-render-engine, rigging

I am facing a problem where I am trying to make the car follow the path made with Bezier Curve, it is rigged, and it was scaled up to fit the size of the road.
The proper model is here:

[image: car model]
(https://gyazo.com/a8aab00c9c7fdf13680043bcb237623f)

After adding the constraint to the model, I cannot rotate the model anymore as it transforms really weirdly, although I need it to make it drift. Photo below:

[image: distorted car model]
(https://gyazo.com/3af59e3197d97dc3e4ab3598bcdef134)

I am trying to follow the video "[How to do a car animation in BLENDER! (Advanced)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=snrlmXjoG6k&ab_channel=WilliamLandgren)" by *WilliamLandgren*

Here is my .blend file (the car model is pretty huge): https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OLVpbHA_NtrG12Ee76xVyl7v1hkFEKsA/view?usp=sharing

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: hello could you please share your file (only the important items)?

Comment: Hey, I only left the car in the .blend file and the drive path. The car seems to be around 150MB, so I had to upload it to Google Drive. By the way, also the tires rotate weirdly; they look sloppy while rotating. Could it be the model? I love the car; maybe I could just change the tires if the rotation problem gets solved.

Comment: are you sure you're sharing the good file? I can't see the deformed car, at what frame is it?

Comment: The point is, if the car follows the path then I want to rotate it so it looks like it drifts. I haven't keyframed the rotation yet, but you can try rotating on different axises

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your curve is squished:

[image]

Select the curve then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> → **Scale**

Scale should be equal in all directions:

[image]

Comment: For some reason, I can not see the curve in my scene anymore, I can select it under collections, but the Apply Scale doesn't apply to it. It is enabled in the viewport.

Comment: It's because you have endered in local mode, press Num "/"

Comment: Thank you, got it solved!